# Generate equal set of number minus to plus with PHP

Tags: php, numbers, days

i need help to create set of numbers below with PHP.

example:

```
$i = 7
```

result:

```
-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3
```

Another example:

```
$i = 3
```

result:

```
-1,0,1
```

Thanks

Comment: One other thought - in case you're creating this set just so you can iterate it, you don't really need it. You just need the starting point and size. So you can do it like:

Comment: `for ($x = -floor($i / 2), $end = $x + $i; $x < $end; $x++) { ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`range`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php), with minimum/maximum values of `+/-floor($i/2)` e.g.

```
$i = 7;
print_r(range(-floor($i / 2), floor($i / 2)));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => -3
    [1] => -2
    [2] => -1
    [3] => 0
    [4] => 1
    [5] => 2
    [6] => 3
)
```

If you want it to work with even numbers, you have to decide whether you want the range to have more negative values or positive values, and adjust the min/max accordingly:

```
$i = 4;
print_r(range(-floor($i / 2), floor($i / 2) - 1));
$i = 4;
print_r(range(1 - floor($i / 2), floor($i / 2)));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => -2
    [1] => -1
    [2] => 0
    [3] => 1
)
Array
(
    [0] => -1
    [1] => 0
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 2
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/Ca6ZS)

Once you decide which direction you prefer to have more values if the input is even, you can make the code work for even & odd values by using `%` to determine if the input is odd or even. For more negative values:

```
print_r(range(-floor($i / 2), floor($i / 2) - ($i + 1) % 2));
```

For more positive values:

```
print_r(range(($i + 1) % 2 - floor($i / 2), floor($i / 2)));
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/qXXjt)

Comment: The range will be 1 too large for even numbers, right? Maybe just add `$i` to the min?

Comment: Oh wait, that's the same. I guess it would be min + $i - 1

Comment: @Don'tPanic you're absolutely right. I've given a couple of options for even numbers.